# How to compare arrays and update quantity?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I have two arrays `inventory` and `cartItems`. Both the arrays have objects in them.

- `inventory` array has a list of all the products.
- `cartItems` array is the one where the user adds the products to the cart.

I want to compare the arrays and then display the items remaining in the inventory.

below is the code:

```js
var inventory =
[
    { item: "apples", price: 19.95, qty: 50 },
    { item: "oranges", price: 20.99, qty: 40 },
    { item: "pineapples", price: 40.00, qty: 60 },
    { item: "lemons", price: 10.12, qty: 100 }
]

function MyBasket() {
  this.totalItems = []
}

MyBasket.prototype.addItems = function(item, price, qty) {
  this.totalItems.push({
    "item": item,
    "price": price,
    "qty": qty
  });
}

MyBasket.prototype.cartItems = function() {
  return this.totalItems;
}

var cart = new MyBasket();

cart.addItems("banana", 10, 2);
cart.addItems("mango", 10, 3);
cart.addItems("x", 5, 4);

console.log('cart items', cart.cartItems())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the `cartItems` and update the `inventory` using `forEach` and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var inventory = [{item:"apples",price:19.95,qty:50},{item:"oranges",price:20.99,qty:40},{item:"pineapples",price:40.00,qty:60},{item:"lemons",price:10.12,qty:100}];

const cart = {
  totalItems: [{
    item: "apples",
    price: 20,
    qty: 2
  }, {
    item: "oranges",
    price: 21,
    qty: 3
  }]
}

function updateInventory() {
  cart.totalItems.forEach(i => {
    const item = inventory.find(o => o.item === i.item);
    
    if(item)
      item.qty -= i.qty;
  })
}

updateInventory()
console.log(inventory)
```

Comment: I am getting an error `Cannot read property 'qty' of undefined`

Comment: That's because you have an item called `x` in `totalItems` which doesn't exist in `inventory`. This might be invalid data. Anyway, I have updated the code to check for `undefined`